# Objective-C: Inheritance and dynamic typing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, inheritance

Say I have two classes:

```
@interface Rectangle: NSObject {
    int width;
    int height;
}

// Methods here...

@end

@interface Square: Rectangle

- (void)initWithLength:(int) length;

@end
```

Square inherits from Rectangle. Now, if I have a method that takes a `Rectangle` in another class, say, `- (void)drawShape:(Rectangle *) rectangle`, can I pass a `Square` object to it? Should I be using `id`? What is the best way to dynamically type inherited classes?

Also: This is just an example. My classes are much more complicated than this. For instance,  categories would not apply for my actual problem. And if I were using an abstract class above `Rectangle`, `Shape` for example, would that change the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a known base class then you should use that. id is useful if you are doing duck typing, but compile time checking is always a good measure against bugs.

id is generally used in concert with protocols. Let's say you have one called MyProtocol. Then you could type a var as id < MyProtocol >. This will allow the compiler to statically verify your code.

Comment: I am using the known base but I get a warning: "Incompatible pointer types passing..." Is that normal?

Comment: Oh sorry. Forget the warning. I forgot to include the .h for the subclass. But thanks for the answer. Good advice!